# Finger detection, extraction and recognition

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, detection

Input : Frontal image of Hand

My project is to detect a human finger shown before the camera and to extract the parts mraked in the image as below and do recognition.

[image]

I tried few opensource codes like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NzmeEml3Wk) Where I could get good accuracy. Can some one provide me some starters or sources to make a move on steps as below?

1) detecting the finger
2) extracting the part marked in the image shown
3) Recognition

Update : Updated the finger image

Comment: What have you tried/thought of? You should come here having tried or at least thought about the problem...
Anyway, standard way is to detect skin with a histogram back-projection or similar, then get the convex-hull and convexity defects to detect fingers. A google with "detecting hands opencv" should already have turned this up though...

Comment: Try saliency map. http://www.samontab.com/web/saliency/

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you can convert the camera images to HSV color space and look for skin colored regions to segment out the hand. For detecting fingers (initialization), you will need to come up with a few assumptions (like whether you need a pre-determined initial hand gesture, whether you differentiate left Vs. right hand etc.). Detecting fingers will largely depend on your assumptions here. Convex hull, as mentioned in the above comment, is quite useful here.

For tracking, camshift tracking can provide a rough tracking for the entire hand. For fingers, you can use "good features to track", ones you have initialized them.